# Read complete data from stream from onMessage

Tags: javascript, websocket

How to read `event.data` completely from a WebSocket using JavaScript?

```
onMessage: function(event) {
 var msg = event.data;
 alert(msg);
}
```

In the above code, the variable `msg` shows only the partial data. How to receive the complete data from the WebSocket server?

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets is a message based transport. If the server has broken the "stream" into several message chunks then you will receive several message events and the first message event won't have all the data that you are expecting.

Also, the WebSocket definition requires that the onmessage handler is called for full messages. You can't get partial messages (unless the browser's WebSocket implementation is broken).

I would try something asynchronous instead of alert() to log the messages you receive. For example, try console.log() if you have Firebug or the Chrome Javascript console. Are you accumulating your message data in the HTML text box or just overwriting it as you receive messages?

Answer (score 0):

`event.data` contains the full information; it just depends on your output how much you'll see. An alert box can only contain up to a specific amount of characters, because more characters simply wouldn't fit in the alert box. `alert`ing is not a good practice for displaying large data.

A more convenient way is to save the length and check that, e.g.:

```
onMessage: function(event) {
    var msg = event.data;
    alert(msg.length);
}
```

The length should just be the correct length, i.e. the length of the characters you sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried again without alert box, this time, I have placed the "event.data" in the HTML text box, still I am receiving part of the data, not complete data.

Comment: @osdevkid: How much is the data? Perhaps the browser also makes a difference. Do you get multiple `onmessage` calls?